# Error in Layout call removeView()

Tags: java, android

i have this problem with my Fragment, this is snipped code:

```
View mLoginFormView;
View mLoginStatusView;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor_css, container, true);

    mLoginFormView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_status);
   return rootView;

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime);



        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

and my layout is:

```
    <merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".Home">


<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_status_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/login_progress_signing_in"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>



<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".ValidationCss" >



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cssEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="@string/urlString" />

</RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

When i try to run i have this problem:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: try `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editor_css, container, false);`

Comment: if i try i have this error:       android.view.InflateException: <merge /> can be used only with a valid ViewGroup root and attachToRoot=true

Comment: you can not have merge tag as root, for fragment

Comment: The <merge/> is used to inline a layout within another to allow easier management of complex layout files. I'm not sure it's supposed to be used as a root for a fragment or activity view? Try using a linearlayout instead and see if the problem persists?